# IBM Integration bus recipient List router for multiple copies of same message to list of nodes

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Please suggest if there is anything similar to recipient-list-router in IBM Integration bus? I am new with working on IIB and all could find was routeToLabel, but it routes to only one receipient based on matched criteria. I want to implement a soapInput node, where in it takes soap request makes 2 copies of it,

- one goes to some default compute and to soapReply
- the second goes to proper processing to MQ/JMS asynchronous calls

So to make 2 copies of received soap request I need something like receipientListRouter in spring integration. Please suggest if any such exists in IIB or other way of doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your simple use case you could just wire the output terminal of the common part of the flow twice, or alternatively if you want to explicitly set the order the branches are taken then you could use the Flow Order node.

If you had a large number of branches instead I would probably use route to label nodes along with a compute node to propagate in a loop modifying the local env value OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.RouterList.DestinationData.labelName each time through the loop.

Additionally I think it would be a really good requirement to submit to get the routeToLabel node to process a list defined in OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.RouterList. You can submit a request for enhancement at the following URI:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532